# How to set cursor position at the end of input text in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I'm trying to set the cursor in a text field with a focus function. I've made some research but none of the provided solutions seemed to work in Google Chrome. In Internet Explorer and Firefox this solution is working fine:

The js:

```
$('#Search').focus(function() {
  var SearchInput = $('#Search');
  var strLength= SearchInput.val().length;
  SearchInput.focus();
  SearchInput[0].setSelectionRange(strLength, strLength);
});
```

The HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="Search" value="Hello World" />
```

Here's the link to my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/esnvh/1/).

Is there any way to make this work in Google Chrome too?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It seems like the focus event is fired before the cursor is placed when you focus an input, a hacky workaround would be to use a setTimeout like so:

```
$('#Search').focus(function() {
    setTimeout((function(el) {
        var strLength = el.value.length;
        return function() {
            if(el.setSelectionRange !== undefined) {
                el.setSelectionRange(strLength, strLength);
            } else {
                $(el).val(el.value);
            }
    }}(this)), 0);
});
```

**Try this fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/esnvh/26/

Edited to 0ms timeout, as @SparK pointed out this is enough to push to end of execution queue.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I haven't thought of that! It seems to work really well. I'll try this approach on my project.

Comment: Works like a charm! I'll mark your answer. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad I could help, updated the answer with a fallback for non chrome browsers. See @Paul-Rad-Dupuy answer

Comment: Oh, I see. I wish I could mark his answer as helpful too, but I don't have enough rep :P Well, thanks again!

Comment: use setTimeout(func, 0); to make func go to the end of execution queue. It will NOT run imediately in a separated thread, you know...

Comment: Great hack! Saved my bacon.

Answer (score 6):

**Updated code**

Reference: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/move-cursor-to-end-of-textarea-or-input/

`setSelectionRange` [is not supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Input.setSelectionRange) on IE, Opera & Safari

I suggest you to make something like this (works on IE, Chrome, Safari, Firefox).

```
$('#Search').on('mouseup', function() {
    var element = $(this)[0];
    if (this.setSelectionRange) {
        var len = $(this).val().length * 2;
        element.setSelectionRange(len, len);
    }
    else {
        $(this).val($(this).val());
        $(this).focus();
    }
    element.scrollTop = 9999;
});
```

**Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/r5UVW/4/**

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I've tried your code, but it doesn't seems to work in Chrome. Is it just me?

Comment: Updated fiddle demo ;-)

Comment: Thanks for updating! :) The thing is that my customer is complaining that when he clicks on the text field, the cursor is not at the end of it. Apparently, in Chrome, the focus action works only with the trigger. Try clicking on the field after the page loads and see what happens please. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks Paul! The problem is that not only clicking on the field should position the cursor, but also when switching from other fields to this one using the keyboard...

Answer (score 4):

Use mouseup event for that:

```
$("#Search").mouseup(function () {
    this.setSelectionRange(this.value.length, this.value.length);    
});
```

Comment: This seems to work, but what if I have more text fields, and start navigating them with Tab key? The real thing is that I'm trying to use with money mask fields.

Answer (score 2):

Without jQuery :)

```
private focusOnLastInput(): void {
  const items = this.fields.querySelectorAll('input');
  const lastInput = items[items.length - 1];
  const valueLength = lastInput.value.length;

  lastInput.focus();
  lastInput.setSelectionRange(valueLength, valueLength);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

FYI, currently the number input doesn't support `setSelectionRange()`, so a quick solution is to simply select the text using `.select()`. On desktop browsers this highlights the text, on mobiles this moves the cursor straight to the end of the text.