# Focus cursor to the end of an input value (CreateView, ModelForm)

Tags: python, django

I have a form with 2 inputs. I am using CreateView and ModelForm. And {% form %}.

Problem:

I need the second input (which already has an initial value) when "tabbed" to, to put the cursor at the end of the string.
Current behavior:
When "tab" to get to the second input, it highlights the entire string.

What I have so far:
I am able to autofocus by adding this line of code to my ModelForm init: 
`self.fields['description'].widget.attrs['autofocus'] = 'on'` .

I was thinking that something like this: 
`self.fields['inc_number'].widget.attrs['onfocus'] = 'INC'[:0]`
("INC is the initial value) might solve the problem. I get no errors, but it still just highlights the entire string when I tab from the description input.

For my code, I will try to focus on just the most relevant parts.

models.py

```py
class ITBUsage(models.Model):
    """ ITB usage """

    itb = models.ForeignKey(IncidentTriageBridge, related_name='itb',
                            on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, verbose_name="ITB name")
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name="Description", null=True)
    inc_number = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name="Incident number", null=True)
    ...
```

views.py

```py
class StartItb(CreateView):
    # class StartItb(CreateView):
    """ Start a bridge by adding a new row in ITBUsage """
    model = models.ITBUsage
    form_class = forms.StartItbForm
    template_name = "itb_tracker/start_form.html"

    initial = {'inc_number': "INC"}  # prefill INC for user

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        """ inject the extra data """
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
        ...
        return kwargs 

    def form_valid(self, form):
        ...
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Above: `initial = {'inc_number': "INC"}` this is currently how I get "INC" into the input

forms.py:

```py
class StartItbForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """ Start a bridge by adding a for in ITBUsage """

    class Meta:
        model = models.ITBUsage
        fields = ['description', 'inc_number']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ...

        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['description'].widget.attrs['autofocus'] = 'on'

    def clean(self):
    ...
        return cleaned_data

    def clean_inc_number(self):
        """ Validate the INC Number is in the correct format """
        inc_number = self.cleaned_data['inc_number']

        if inc_number and not re.match(r'INC[0-9]+', inc_number):
            raise forms.ValidationError("Format must be 'INC' followed by a number. For example: 'INC123456'")
        return inc_number

    def save(self, commit=True):
        """ inject extra data """
        ...
        return super().save(commit)
```

Above: `self.fields['description'].widget.attrs['autofocus'] = 'on'` is how I make it set the cursor to the first input (description) when directed to the page.

My form html is simply using the {% form %} with some Bootstrap 4. Functionally works as expected. BUT this is why I am unable to put the onfocus logic directly on the input.

Desired behavior:
After the user finished typing in 'description', hit 'Tab', cursor goes to the end of "INC" (initial value) of the 'inc_number' input.   (intention is so that they do not delete "INC" but rather add to the end of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So based on help from "rje", this is what I did to solve the problem.

I needed to not set the initial in the view.
But instead `self.fields['inc_number'].initial = "INC"` in the form.
So that I could get the length (rather than hard coding to 3).
`length = len(self.fields['inc_number'].initial)` .

with the solution line being
`self.fields['inc_number'].widget.attrs['onfocus'] = 'this.setSelectionRange(length, length)'`

Answer (score 2):

The `widget.attrs` contains HTML attributes for your widget. You can set the `onfocus` attribute and that has to be a JavaScript function.

So it should look something like this:

`self.fields['inc_number'].widget.attrs['onfocus'] = 'this.setSelectionRange(..)`

Although I'm not sure that works everywhere - see this post: [How to set cursor position at the end of input text in Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21881509/how-to-set-cursor-position-at-the-end-of-input-text-in-google-chrome)

Comment: So there is not a python way to do it? Should it really accept that Javascript as a string?

Comment: No, you cannot do this in python because this is something that needs to be handled in the browser. You would typically write javascript for that.

Comment: So regardless of the `self.fields['inc_number'].widget.attrs['onfocus']`, there is no way to solve my problem within my current Python Django?

Comment: Think about it this way: your django server sends html to the browser, containing an `input` tag for your form field. When the user takes action (like pressing TAB) to focus your input field, you want the browser to take action and move the cursor. All of that takes place long after django sent the HTML. The python code plays no role here anymore. Instead, to make the browser do this, you have it execute JavaScript.

Comment: Ok yes that does make sense. So what I really need to figure out is how to add Javascript to my ModelForm at runtime (if possible).

Comment: the `widget.attrs` let you do exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

In your `FormView`, override `get_form()` as below.

```
class ExampleFormView(FormView):

    ...

    def get_form(self):
        form = super().get_form()
        # ensure autofocus cursor is at the end of the prefilled (initial) text
        length = len(form.initial['name'])
        form.fields['name'].widget.attrs['onfocus'] = f'this.setSelectionRange({length}, {length})'
        return form

    def get_initial(self):
        initial = super().get_initial()
        initial['name'] = 'Example initial name'
        return initial

    ...
```

Also make sure `autofocus` is set on the `ModelForm`.

forms.py

```
class ExampleForm(forms.ModelForm):   
    class Meta:
        model = ExampleModel
        fields = ['name']
        widgets = {
            'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={
                'autofocus': True,
            }),
        }
```